# Pandas - column with list of index for another data frame python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with one of its column holding index of another data frame, I want to create one more column in this data frame with dictionary holding index as key and value from a column in another data frame.

Example,

```
Dataset1

  A B C
0 9 1 [1,3]
1 7 2 [0,1]
```

In the above dataset, column C has indices of dataset2.

```
Dataset2
  A B C D
0 1 4 3 8
1 2 3 5 7
3 4 6 9 8
```

And my output dataset should have a new column in dataset1 with key as indices of dataset2 and value as values of column D from dataset2.
So the output should look like,

```
Dataset1
   A   B    C    D
0  9   1  [1,3] {'1':'7','3':'8'}
1  7   2  [0,1] {'0':'8','1':'7'}
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dict comprehension` with maping by `dict` created by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = Dataset2['D'].to_dict()

Dataset1['D'] = Dataset1['C'].apply(lambda x: {str(y):str(d[y]) for y in x})
print (Dataset1)
   A  B       C                     D
0  9  1  [1, 3]  {'1': '7', '3': '8'}
1  7  2  [0, 1]  {'0': '8', '1': '7'}
```

Another solution with list and dict comprehensions:

```
Dataset1['D'] = [{str(y):str(d[y]) for y in x} for x in Dataset1['C']]
print (Dataset1)
   A  B       C                     D
0  9  1  [1, 3]  {'1': '7', '3': '8'}
1  7  2  [0, 1]  {'0': '8', '1': '7'}
```